# Change Mylyn subtask hierarchy in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I've created a task hierarchy in Mylyn that looks something like:

```
> Category 'A'
> Category 'B'
  - Task B.1
  - Task B.2
     - Subtask B.2.a
     - Subtask B.2.b
```

Now I want to modify the hierarchy so that Subtask B.2.a is a subtask of Task B.1 instead of B.2. Is there a way to do this in the Eclipse Mylyn plugin? I though I could just do a D-n-D but that didn't work. Not sure it matters but for what its worth I'm using Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 on a Ubuntu machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I stumbled on the answer to my own question... you can reorder the task and sub-task hierarchy using drag-n-drop BUT the task must first be activated. As far as I can tell, this isn't documented anywhere but maybe I overlooked it. If not, it should be added.